# How to run "adb push" command before launching an activity from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

I have some test data for my program that i want to push to the device before a test activity is run or debug. On the command line this is:

```
adb -s  RF8M40T69JX  push --sync -z any test_data /storage/emulated/0/Download/test_data
```

I know i can run an external tool shell script with the "Before launch" configuration option. But this does not give me any way to know on which device Studio want to start it. I don't want to waste the time and dispatch to every possible device and every Edit-Compile-Run cycle.

I checked that the device signature is unfortunately not passed as environment variable to external tools as it should be. Is there any other way? Can i do this with some Gradle magic?

Comment: Same problem here, it would facilitate my life if there was a method of doing it

Answer (score 0):

As of Android Studio Giraffe "2022.3.1" it is still impossible to do.